# How to wrap div around items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wrapall

My code wraps a div around every 5 child divs.
But the wrapping should only take place in the div "partnerwrap", can someone help me?

```js
var divs = $(".partnerwrap > .partner_item");
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i += 5) {
  divs.slice(i, i + 5).wrapAll("<div class='group'></div>");
}
```

```css
.partner_item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content1">
  <div class="partnerwrap">
    <div class="partner_item even">1</div>
    <div class="partner_item odd">2</div>
    <div class="partner_item even">3</div>
    <div class="partner_item odd">4</div>
    <div class="partner_item even">5</div>
    <div class="partner_item odd">6</div>
    <div class="partner_item even">7</div>
    <div class="partner_item odd">8</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="content2">
  <div class="partnerwrap">
    <div class="partner_item even">9</div>
    <div class="partner_item odd">10</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JSFIDDLE:**
http://jsfiddle.net/nvnLa/1/embedded/result/

Comment: Bypassing the JSFiddle warning by posting your link within code tags will not get you anything other than a few downvotes here on SO. Please post your code within the question, as you were instructed yet chose to avoid.

Comment: Sorry James, i translated the code message wrong.

Comment: In this case you should make to distinct selects, one for each content div.
Is your code limited to 2 content divs or do you want a ways to ma several wraps in different content divs?

**Edit:** One More question, why do you have divs with class `content1` and `conten2`, do you use them to apply css or just to identify the divs?

Comment: No, my code is not limited to 2. The classes "content1" and "content2" are only to identify, that there a several more divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Ids to identify the content divs, and use class to group them, you can do something like this:

```js
$(".content").each(function() {
  var divs = $(".partnerwrap > .partner_item", this);
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i += 5) {
    divs.slice(i, i + 5).wrapAll("<div class='group'></div>");
  }
});
```

```css
.partner_item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content1">
  <div class="partnerwrap">
    <div class="partner_item even">1</div>
    <div class="partner_item odd">2</div>
    <div class="partner_item even">3</div>
    <div class="partner_item odd">4</div>
    <div class="partner_item even">5</div>
    <div class="partner_item odd">6</div>
    <div class="partner_item even">7</div>
    <div class="partner_item odd">8</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="content2">
  <div class="partnerwrap">
    <div class="partner_item even">9</div>
    <div class="partner_item odd">10</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Check it in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nvnLa/2/)

Comment: Thanks, are the ids important?

Comment: If you want to identify the divs you should use ids, if you don't have any code that looks for those divs you can remove them. the important part will be that the divs have the same class, so you can get them a find the `.partner_item` inside them.